# Delete all SYSTEM V shared memory and semaphores on UNIX-like systems

Tags: linux, unix, posix, semaphore, shared-memory

How can I delete all not used semaphores and shared memory with a single command on a UNIX-like system, e.g., Ubuntu?

Comment: This question really needs an explanation of "Why".

Comment: i'm doing a school project in c

Comment: So, as usual with homework, what do you know, what have you tried?

Comment: i'm working with semaphores and shared memory in a network file system

Comment: Yeh good god guys, show a little understanding. The same question siome has occurs to me right now. Registering some sys v shared memory and needing a cleanup after a while, who wants to invoke "ipcrm" multiple times, parsing "ipcs" beforehand. Programming is lazyness. And stackoverflow is for especialy lazy programmers, isn't it?

Comment: All solutions yet do not take POSIX semaphores (named as well as unnamed) into account but focus on XSI aka SystemV semaphores only. That's not a big surprise since the question is rather poor quality. However, the stackexchange community does better normally - I am surprised.

Comment: **You can break your running system if you do such a thing**.  There is no possibility of doing that and only `ipcrm(1)` command allows you to delete other program's created ipc resources, but resource by resource.

Answer (score 67):

Here, save and try this script (kill_ipcs.sh) on your shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

ME=`whoami`

IPCS_S=`ipcs -s | egrep "0x[0-9a-f]+ [0-9]+" | grep $ME | cut -f2 -d" "`
IPCS_M=`ipcs -m | egrep "0x[0-9a-f]+ [0-9]+" | grep $ME | cut -f2 -d" "`
IPCS_Q=`ipcs -q | egrep "0x[0-9a-f]+ [0-9]+" | grep $ME | cut -f2 -d" "`


for id in $IPCS_M; do
  ipcrm -m $id;
done

for id in $IPCS_S; do
  ipcrm -s $id;
done

for id in $IPCS_Q; do
  ipcrm -q $id;
done
```

We use it whenever we run IPCS programs in the university student server. Some people don't always cleanup so...it's needed :P

Comment: Doesn't that delete all of them, even if `nattach` is nonzero? What about this?: `ipcs -m | egrep "0x[0-9a-f]+ [0-9]+"|awk '{ if ($6 == 0) { print $2; } }'|xargs -n1 ipcrm -m`

Comment: I would replace the for loops with `xargs`: `echo $IPCS_S | xargs -n1 ipcrm -s`.

Comment: For me the above regex didn't work. The following did `IPCS_Q=`ipcs -q | egrep -i "0x[0-9a-f]+.*[0-9]+" | grep $ME | cut -f2 -d" "``

Comment: On AIx systems does not work either.. some minor tweaks on the commands did the trick! 
`ipcs -s |grep $ME |  awk '{print $2}'`
The awk command solves the positioning problems.

Answer (score 11):

This works on my Mac OS:

```
for n in `ipcs -b -m | egrep ^m | awk '{ print $2; }'`; do ipcrm -m $n; done
```

Answer (score 10):

```
ipcs -s | grep $USERNAME | perl -e 'while (<STDIN>) { @a=split(/\s+/); print `ipcrm sem $a[1]`}'
```

or

```
ipcs -s | grep $USERNAME | awk ' { print $2 } ' | xargs ipcrm sem
```

Change $USERNAME to a real username.

Answer (score 10):

```
#!/bin/bash
ipcs -m | grep `whoami` | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs -n1 ipcrm -m
ipcs -s | grep `whoami` | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs -n1 ipcrm -s
ipcs -q | grep `whoami` | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs -n1 ipcrm -q
```

Comment: It's a great answer, it helped me to remove queues with key 0x0 (which cannot be removed using ipcrm -Q option)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how to delete all at once, but you can use `ipcs` to list resources, and then use loop and delete with `ipcrm`. This should work, but it needs a little work. I remember that I made it work once in class.

Comment: Do we know if he is using SysV ipc and not POSIX?

Comment: @Duck We know he's using Ubuntu, and I checked those commands on Ubuntu

Comment: Right but ipcs only works with SysV ipc objects.  If he is using the posix versions they will show in /dev/shm where he can just rm them.

Answer (score 2):

Check if there is anything to delete with :

```
ipcs -a | grep `whoami`
```

On linux delete them all via :

```
ipcs | nawk -v u=`whoami` '/Shared/,/^$/{ if($6==0&&$3==u) print "ipcrm shm",$2,";"}/Semaphore/,/^$/{ if($3==u) print "ipcrm sem",$2,";"}' | /bin/sh
```

For sun it would be :

```
ipcs -a | nawk -v u=`whoami` '$5==u &&(($1=="m" && $9==0)||($1=="s")){print "ipcrm -"$1,$2,";"}' | /bin/sh
```

courtsesy of di.uoa.gr

Check again if all is ok

For deleting *your* sems/shared mem - supposing you are a user in a workstation with no admin rights

Answer (score 2):

1 line will do all

For message queue

```
ipcs -q | sed "$ d; 1,2d" |  awk '{ print "Removing " $2; system("ipcrm -q " $2) }'
```

`ipcs -q` will give the records of message queues

`sed "$ d; 1,2d "`  will remove last blank line (`"$ d"`) and first two header lines (`"1,2d"`)

`awk` will do the rest i.e. printing and removing using command `"ipcrm -q"` w.r.t. the value of column 2 (`coz $2`)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it in FreeBSD:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
for i in $(ipcs -a | grep "^s" | awk '{ print $2 }');
do
        echo "ipcrm -s $i"
        ipcrm -s $i
done
```

Answer (score 1):

to remove all shared memory segments on FreeBSD

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(ipcs -m | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed 1,2d);
do
    echo "ipcrm -m $i"
    ipcrm -m $i
done
```

to remove all semaphores

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(ipcs -s | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed 1,2d);
do
    echo "ipcrm -s $i"
    ipcrm -s $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you're working on a NFS system, do you have access to those semaphores and [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory)? I think you misunderstood what they are, they are an API code that enables processes to communicate with each other, [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming))s are a solution for preventing race conditions and for threads to communicate with each other, in simple answer, they do not leave any residue on any filesystem.

Unless you are using an socket or a pipe? Do you have the necessary permissions to remove them, why are they on an NFS system?

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: no this doesn't help me...i'm just doing a simple c project for a fake nfs...i know what are semaphores and shared memory...i just want to do some test on my code and i need to remove all the shared data in one click

Comment: @simone: You should have stated 'fake nfs' on your original question and pointed out that you understood semaphores and shared memory... it is still not clear as to what is "shared data"?

Comment: And also inclusion of code as well to show your homework for us SO'ers to see....that would be of help also...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to bvamos's answer, according to the documentation the use of `sem` is deprecated :

> NAME ipcrm - remove a message queue, semaphore set or shared memory id
>   SYNOPSIS ipcrm [ -M key | -m id | -Q key | -q id | -S key | -s id ]
>   ... deprecated usage
>
> ipcrm [ shm | msg | sem ] id ...

**remove shared memory**

us `ipcrm -m` to remove a shared memory segment by the id

```
#!/bin/bash

set IPCS_M = ipcs -m | egrep "0x[0-9a-f]+ [0-9]+" | grep $USERNAME | cut -f2 -d" "

for id in $IPCS_M; do
  ipcrm -m $id;
done
```

or `ipcrm -M` to remove a shared memory segment by the key

```
#!/bin/bash

set IPCS_M = ipcs -m | egrep "0x[0-9a-f]+ [0-9]+" | grep $USERNAME | cut -f1 -d" "

for id in $IPCS_M; do
  ipcrm -M $id;
done
```

**remove message queues**

us `ipcrm -q` to remove a shared memory segment by the id

```
#!/bin/bash

set IPCS_Q = ipcs -q | egrep "0x[0-9a-f]+ [0-9]+" | grep $USERNAME | cut -f2 -d" "

for id in $IPCS_Q; do
  ipcrm -q $id;
done
```

or `ipcrm -Q` to remove a shared memory segment by the key

```
#!/bin/bash

set IPCS_Q = ipcs -q | egrep "0x[0-9a-f]+ [0-9]+" | grep $USERNAME | cut -f1 -d" "

for id in $IPCS_Q; do
  ipcrm -Q $id;
done
```

**remove semaphores**

us `ipcrm -s` to remove a semaphore segment by the id

```
#!/bin/bash

set IPCS_S = ipcs -s | egrep "0x[0-9a-f]+ [0-9]+" | grep $USERNAME | cut -f2 -d" "

for id in $IPCS_S; do
  ipcrm -s $id;
done
```

or `ipcrm -S` to remove a semaphore segment by the key

```
#!/bin/bash

set IPCS_S = ipcs -s | egrep "0x[0-9a-f]+ [0-9]+" | grep $USERNAME | cut -f1 -d" "

for id in $IPCS_S; do
  ipcrm -S $id;
done
```