# How can I delete unused shared memory and semaphores?

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

Similar to: [Delete all shared memory and semaphores on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143404/delete-all-shared-memory-and-semaphores-on-linux) however, I want to do so in C, not with some script.

My specific problem: in linux + mac, when I debug a program and terminate it mid process, the shared resources (memory + semaphores) arent released. My program does some client server stuff where the server is the first process to acquire the shared resources. Therefore, after a termination without detaching, when I restart the program, it assumes that it is the client when there is no server (because the resource has been created and not released).

Currently, I am using Qt to manage the shared resources but Qt does not appear to have a way to deal with this situation (the error code that create returns is that the resource has already been created). Therefore, Im looking to a more OS specific way to do this. NOTE: windows does not have this problem because the shared resource is released on termination automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `man ipcrm`.

> ipcrm - remove a message queue, semaphore set or shared memory id

Does the server terminate normally? If so you can have it call `shmdt()` before exiting.
If it is crashing, then that's a little harder.  One thing is to have it use `shmctl` to
see how many processes have the `shm` attached.  If it's 0, then you are obviously not the client.

There's also a flag you can set on shm segments `IPC_RMID`, although the usage seems a little ambiguous.

Comment: No, the server crashes. I am currently looking at shmctl, thanks!