# Delete shared memory linux with ipcrm

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I am writing a simple application on C that uses shared memory but I cannot run it anymore as it says:

`shmat: Cannot allocate memory`

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4262545/2587048) script to free my memory but doesn't seem to work.

This is a screenshot of my processes:

[image]

This is the application code:

```
/* Shared Memory IPC creates a mamory space and send contendt to it while the other process can read from it.
Our implementation works like this:
    1. First run the application by passing as a argument the value you want to send to the shared memory. Example: ./ipc_sharedmem.o 4
    2. Run the appliation again to read from the shared memory (which is a new process, of course) wihout sending any arguments. Exmaple: ./ipc_sharedmem.o
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#define SHM_SIZE 1024  /* make it a 1K shared memory segment */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    key_t key;
    int shared_mem_mid;
    char *data;

    struct timeval t1, t2, t3, t4;

    if (argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: shmdemo [data_to_write]\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* make the key: */
    if ((key = ftok("mach.c", 'R')) == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* connect to (and possibly create) the segment: */
    if ((shared_mem_mid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, 0644 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* attach to the segment to get a pointer to it: */
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    data = (char *) shmat(shared_mem_mid, (void *)0, 0);
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    if (data == (char *)(-1)) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Time to read the message from sharem memory: %g \n", (t2.tv_sec + t2.tv_usec/1000000.0)-(t1.tv_sec + t1.tv_usec/1000000.0));

    /* read or modify the segment, based on the command line: */
    if (argc == 2) {
        printf("writing to segment: \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
        gettimeofday(&t3, NULL);
        strncpy(data, argv[1], SHM_SIZE);
        gettimeofday(&t4, NULL);
        printf("Time to send data to shared memory: %g \n", (t4.tv_sec + t4.tv_usec/1000000.0)-(t3.tv_sec + t3.tv_usec/1000000.0));
    } else{

        printf("segment contains: \"%s\"\n", data);
    }
    /* detach from the segment: */
    if (shmdt(data) == -1) {
        perror("shmdt");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your shared memory segments are marked as to be destroyed but still have process(es) attached to them.

Per the [source code](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/busybox/util-linux/ipcs.c#237), the `nattach` column is 2 and the `status` is "dest", meaning the shared memory segments have 2 attachments and are marked to be destroyed once the last attached process detaches from the segment.

You need to either have the process(es) attached to the segments call `shmdt()` to detach from the shared memory segments, or you need kill those process(es).  Once you do that the segments will be destroyed.

Comment: Can you give me a code example how I " either have the process(es) attached to the segments call shmdt() to detach from the shared memory segments". Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried (as root):

```
$ sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Not sure this will free your shared memory, but you can try.

If you want to see an example, here goes a gist: https://gist.github.com/hudsantos/7fec7d9c34cc472b7f98

Comment: Could you please provide us with your 'simple application' source code? Not whole code, just key commands you are executing and getting that error.

Comment: I've executed your code and had no problem:
hudson@vostrolab /tmp/c $ touch mach.c
hudson@vostrolab /tmp/c $ ./a 4
Time to read the message from sharem memory: 1.38283e-05 
writing to segment: "4"
Time to send data to shared memory: 2.09808e-05 
hudson@vostrolab /tmp/c $ ./a
Time to read the message from sharem memory: 1.28746e-05 
segment contains: "4"

Comment: That is normal, I have run this code many times before but now that shared memory is full I don't know how to free it.